# Database in conjunction with Barcodes

Tags: database, barcode-scanner

This is sort of a broad question - hope I'm posting in the right board ....

How can I go apart setting up a database (Im thinking about access here? )

I want to set up some fields for my company - such as name , number , address , email address etc etc.

I have a dymo label printer to print out the barcodes. Ive tried inputting the information on the barcode itself but the barcode becomes 'too big to print' , so I want to be able to link a database to the barcode so when its scanned it will load up all the information.

Sorry I have no code - I just have no place to start ):

Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 3):

If the barcode is too large, you can change its size in Properties in DYMO Label.

There is a function in DYMO Label called Import Data and Print. You can design a label with barcode and text objects, then select a file and link columns to objects (basic drag and drop). I hope that answers the question.